# “Syntax error: Operator expected” in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this graph structure representing data flow in Prolog.

- I have an edge from node 1 to 2, 1 to 3, etc.
- Variable x is defined in node 1, variable t in node 4, etc.
- Variable d is used in node 4, variable x in node 7, etc.

The function `definition_clear_path` should compute the [definition-clear path](http://www.ironiacorp.com/Projects/Testing/Definition-clear_path) of any variable.

When I run this I get the following error:

```
definition_clear_path/3: Undefined procedure: definition_clear_path1/4
         However, there are definitions for:
               definition_clear_path/3
```

When I enter the rule for `definition_clear_path1` from the terminal I get `Syntax error: Operator expected`. Why?

```
edge(1, 2).
edge(1,3).
edge(3,7).
edge(3,4).
edge(4,6).
edge(4,5).
edge(7,x).
def(p,1).
def(e,1).
def(d,1).
def(x,1).
def(c,1).
def(d,4).
def(t,4).
def(c,5).
def(x, 6).
def(c,6).
use(d,3).
use(e,3).
use(d,4).
use(c,4).
use(x,4).
use(t,4).
use(c,5).
use(x,6).
use(c,6).
use(d,6).
use(x,7).
pos_path(X,Y, [X,Y]):- edge(X,Y).
pos_path(Start, End, [Start|T]) :- edge(Start,Mid), pos_path(Mid, End, T).


definition_clear_path( Node , J , Var ):- definition_clear_path1( Node , J , Var , [    Node ] ) .

definition_clear_path1(B , J, K , F):- edge (B , J ).

definition_clear_path1( Node , J , Var , L):- 
edge ( Node , N1 ) ,
not(def( Var , N1 )) ,
not(use( Var , N1 )) ,
definition_clear_path1( N1 , J , Var , [ Node | L ] ) .
```

Comment: If you put definition_clear_path at the end, does the error goes away?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the space between `edge` and the opening parenthesis.

Spaces delimit terms, so Prolog will think that `edge` is an operator rather than the functor of a compound term.